# Visual Basic - System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net

So my part of the code that gives me problems is this one. It says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array

for `Label1.Text = question(i - 1,0)` and I really don't understand.

I am at the start and I am really trying to learn things for programming.

```
Public Class Test1
Dim question(2, 5) As String
Dim i As Integer = 2
Private Sub Test1_Load()
    question(1, 0) = "2+2="
    question(1, 1) = "1"
    question(1, 2) = "2"
    question(1, 3) = "3"
    question(1, 4) = "4"
    question(2, 0) = "How old are you?"
    question(2, 1) = "12"
    question(2, 2) = "13"
    question(2, 3) = "17"
    question(2, 4) = "18"
    Label1.Text = question(i - 1, 0)
    nr1.Text = question(i - 1, 1)
    nr2.Text = question(i - 1, 2)
    nr3.Text = question(i - 1, 3)
    nr4.Text = question(i - 1, 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: For future reference VB.NET and VBA are not the same. VBA is the language you use to create macros in Microsoft Office.

Comment: What is the value of `i` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Mmm, the value of i is 2.. i think. I am not really what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't give me any errors on dotnetfiddle.net. So "question" is a 2D array indexed from 0-2 and 0-5. Here's what it kinda looks like:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5
0  s   s   s   s   s   s
1  s   s   s   s   s   s
2  s   s   s   s   s   s
```

Where each 's' represents a string. So if you're accessing question(0, 0), then it would be the 's' in the top left. If you're accessing question(0, 1), then it would be the 's' to the right of that one. If you try to access something outside of the bounds of your array, you will get an error, for example, if you try to access question(3, 0).

So to fix your error, you need to figure out what the value of i is. Try putting

```
MessageBox.Show(i)
```

right before the line that's giving you the error.

Comment: thank you very much, now I know where I was wrong. :D